# Search a regular expression for a word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make something where a user can type in a string, `!exchange` and then a word after. If the word after exchange matches the word huntsman, for example, I want it to do one thing, and another thing for a different word.

I've tried to do

```
var req = msg.match(/^!exchange/i); //msg is the string that I'm testing
```

But that doesn't work. I've also tried

```
var req = msg.match(/^!exchange \b/i);
```

But I get the same result. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Be specific.

Comment: By doesn't work, I mean that the match method doesn't find a match for !exchange <word> in the msg string.

Comment: If '!exchange' is first word in string, it should be found, otherwise, if it can be in any place inside msg string - remove '^'.

Comment: no repro: `!!"!exchange hello".match(/^!exchange/i)` is `true`

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2xh0zLLd/

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski— *match* returns either null for no matches, or an array matches. If a boolean is required, then the OP should use *test*.

Comment: That works, but how do I select the second word in the string?

Comment: @RobG I know that, I just wanted to show it works by using the *same* method the OP used.

Comment: What is in msg? How are you using req afterwards? Some (brief) context would help.

Comment: @dragonbanshee use a capture group `msg.match(/^!exchange\s+(\w+)/i)`

Comment: ..and your second word be req[1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the word after `!exchange`, use a capture group:

```
/^!exchange\s+(\w+)/i
```

Now `req[1]` will contain the word after `!exchange`.

```js
function doit(input) {
  var msg = input.value;
  var req = msg.match(/^!exchange\s+(\w+)/i);
  if (req) {
    document.getElementById("result").textContent = req[1];
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" onchange="doit(this)">
<br>Word is <span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this:

`var msg = "!exchange apple";
 msg.match(/^!exchange (.*)/i);`

(which returns `["!exchange apple", "apple"]`)

[String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array of the original string, followed by any matching groups. You'll need to match each word after "!exchange" as a group to get them back in the array.